# access web services with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, web-services

```
 $scope.url = "http://localhost/MerchantProgramService.svc/GetMerchantProfile";
myXHRService.getData($scope.url).then(function(data) {
    alert(data);
    var xhrData = angular.fromJson(data);
    // $scope.xhrData = xhrData.data.children;
});
```

I am trying to access web services with angularjs and i am failed to do it as i am new to angular.

POST http://localhost/MerchantProgramService.svc/GetMerchantProfile 404 (Not Found)

i am getting this error in console. i am using google chorme and using CORS extension to Access cross origin.

Comment: Quite simply that URL doesn't exist on the server (error 404)

Comment: If its GET url, before using it in angular code, just directly access from browser, try to get data and make sure URL is correct.

Comment: when i am access this url from browser it shows **Endpoint not found**.

Comment: what does that mean? is it means that url is not correct ?

Comment: Mostly your URL is incorrect. I see that port after localhost is missing. Few other things might also be  wrong with that. confirm your URL.

Comment: i have many methods like **GetMerchantProfile** some of them are working fine with this URL but others are not.